# github and commit reference in issue

Tags: git, github

i'd like to see the commits reference in our issues.

As you know github  allows to see them only for the default branch (usually master).
We switched to our development branch as a workaround, but it's not useful anymore since we started using the feature branch methodology.

Any suggestion?
Would it be possible to set the default branch before each push so that it reference the commit into the issue when it is written in the commit msg?

UPDATE
i'm probably wrong about the commit, i'll test soon and check the answer given. By the way, documentation says:

```
If the commit is in a non-default branch, the issue will remain open and the issue will be referenced with a tooltip.
```

any way to allow the "close issue #123" from a non default branch ?

Comment: Commit references work fine for me on any branch and show up immediately on the issues...

Comment: Confirmed, they work, the problem is about closing the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't seen any problems with referencing commits to issues from any branch. I have even seen the commits from forked repo's mentioned in the issues. You just have to mention the issues as described in this [page](https://github.com/blog/957-introducing-issue-mentions).